# What is the difference between section 8 and section 515 housing in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, housing, government

I have been looking for an apartment. I found a place that is inexpensive, and I did more research and discovered that it is section 515 housing.

Apparently this is among the types of housing people refer to as *the projects*.

What is the difference between section 8 and section 515?  I live in Tennessee.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this website](http://ruralhousingcoalition.org/section-515-rural-rental-housing-loans), for=profit or non-profit groups can get inexpensive loans to create low-cost housing in rural areas using the section 515 provisions. So it's not a direct-to-renter program, but for the owner/landlord to subsidize the creation of low-cost rental housing.

Section 8 provides vouchers to people who want to rent and have limited income. After a family finds a place, the apartment must be inspected and approved.